# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from googletrans import Translator

def Listen():
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source,0,6)

    try:
        print("Regognizing...") 
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language = "hi")

    except: 
        return ""

    query = str(query).lower()
    return query






def TranslationHintoEng(Text):
    line = str(Text)
    translate = Translator()
    result = translate.translate(line)
    data = result.text
    print(f"You : {data}")
    return data

TranslationHintoEng("कैसा है जारविस मेरी आवाज आ रही है")
```

When i Run this:

```
PS E:\Coding\Python\AI -2\Pyttsx3 Hindi STT> & C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe "e:/Coding/Python/AI -2/Pyttsx3 Hindi STT/Body/Listen.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Coding\Python\AI -2\Pyttsx3 Hindi STT\Body\Listen.py", line 35, in <module>
    TranslationHintoEng("कैसा है जारविस मेरी आवाज आ रही है")
  File "e:\Coding\Python\AI -2\Pyttsx3 Hindi STT\Body\Listen.py", line 30, in TranslationHintoEng
    result = translate.translate(line)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 182, in translate
    data = self._translate(text, dest, src, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 78, in _translate
    token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 194, in do       
    self._update()
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 62, in _update
    code = self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1).replace('var ', '')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
PS E:\Coding\Python\AI -2\Pyttsx3 Hindi STT>
```

I wanted it to translate the text, but when I am running it shows the atrribute error as shown above. If possible please help me and ya thats all and i am stuck here for an hour now I am on python 10.8

Comment: You should note that Google Translate (API) is not free. The implementor(s) of the Python googletrans module are trying to reverse-engineer the token required for API authentication (token.py). Very unethical

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

```
pip install googletrans==3.1.0a0
```

Then:

```
from googletrans import Translator

def TranslationHintoEng(line):
    return Translator(service_urls=['translate.googleapis.com']).translate(line, dest='en').text


print(TranslationHintoEng("कैसा है जारविस मेरी आवाज आ रही है"))
```

**Output:**

```
how are you jarvis my voice is coming
```